# get full text from pubmed

Tags: python, biopython, pubmed

I am using the python api Bio to access to the pubmed central database but unfortunately I can get only the abstract from this api
I want to know if it's possible to get the full text and how

molp5 is a file containing a listing of molecules like below

```
Flavopiridol
4-azapaullone
```

here is my code:

```
def search(query):
    Entrez.email = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed', 
                            sort='relevance', 
                            retmax='3000',
                            retmode='text',
                            rettype='Medline', 
                            term=query)
    results = Entrez.read(handle)
    return results

def fetch_details(id_list):
    ids = ','.join(id_list)
    Entrez.email = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db='pubmed',
                           retmode='xml',
                           id=ids)
    results = Entrez.read(handle)
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #load the file containing the name of the molecules
    mol = pd.read_csv('/W2V/molp5.csv')


    mol["idx"] = mol["idx"].apply(lambda x:lower(x))

    txt = ""
    retmax = []
    for m in mol["idx"]:
        results = search(m)
            #print the number of article available and the name of the molecule
            print m, results['RetMax']
            id_list = results['IdList']
            papers = fetch_details(id_list)
            for i, paper in enumerate(papers):
        try:
            #concatenate the abstract together
            txt += paper['MedlineCitation']['Article']['ArticleTitle']
            for j in paper['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Abstract']['AbstractText']:
                txt += j+'\n'  
            except KeyError:
            pass
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to describe *exactly* what is wrong with your script and provide example values that are in `molp5.csv`. Also, you do realize that PubMed doesn't store full-text articles, it's PubMedCentral?

Comment: Hello , my code is working , I don't want to debug it I just want to know if pubmedcentral provide something to extract the full text

Comment: Discovered [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/tools/oa-service/) with a few seconds of googling...

Comment: this may be useful also https://github.com/knmkr/pubmed-downloader